# CakePHP Unit tests are ignoring Fixtures/test databases and using application's data/databases

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-4.x

I have a legacy application which is running on CakePHP 4.3.8. Historically this application never had any unit tests but we're starting to add them as we work on new features.

The application uses 8 different MariaDB database connections. These are configured in `config/app_local.php` and all have their own key. There is a corresponding "test" database for each one prefixed with `test_`. As an example:

- `dev_notification_db`: Local database for a system notifications feature of the app.
- `test_notification_db`: Test database for the above

All database names follow this convention and have appropriate credentials and connection details to a local install of MariaDB 10.x. A schema with the appropriate name has been created locally and access has been granted to the user/pass referenced in the configuration. We have not had any connection or permissions errors.

In the `dev_notification_db` there are around 3400 rows of data.

I'm trying to write some unit tests following CakePHP's [Testing](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html) docs. In this case I want `test_notification_db` to contain just 3 rows of data since for a particular test I'm writing I don't need all 3400 rows from the application database and certainly don't want them in a version controlled Fixture.

I have created a Fixture in `tests/Fixture/NotificationsFixture.php` which contains the 3 rows I want to add to the test database, `test_notification_db`. This file was created using the following command:

```
bin/cake bake fixture --connection dev_notification_db --conditions 1=1 --count 3400 --records Notifications
```

When the file was created it contained *all* 3400 rows of data from `dev_notification_db`. I manually removed all but the 3 of them that were necessary for testing purposes. The reason I did it in this way is because using the command above also reads the table structure and adds it to `NotificationsFixture.php`, meaning the table with the same columns/data types can be created on `test_notification_db`.

`NotificationsFixture.php` looks like this

```
class NotificationsFixture extends TestFixture
{
    public $fields = [
         // This is essentially the schema of the `notifications` table
         // e.g. 'id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => null, 'unsigned' => true, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'autoIncrement' => true, 'precision' => null]
         // Other columns...
    ];

    public function init(): void
    {
        $this->records = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'column1' => 'foo',
            'column2' => 'bar',
            'column3' => 'baz',
        ],
        // Other rows of test data... 
    }
}
```

In the `init()` method above, `$this->records` contains 3 rows of data which are the ones I want to use in my fixture.

According to the [Creating Fixtures](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#creating-fixtures) section of the CakePHP docs, it says

> Fixtures defines the records that **will be inserted into the test database** at the beginning of each test.

Therefore my understanding is that the 3 rows in `$this->records` should end up in the `test_notification_db` when I'm running my tests.

There isn't anything else in the `NotificationsFixture.php` file, for example something telling it to use a different Data Source from the `app_local.php` config file: it has `$fields` and the `init()` method, and that's all.

My test for this is in `tests/TestCase/Model/Table/NotificationsTest.php`. One of my tests relies on it reading the Fixture data, i.e. the 3 rows from `test_notification_db`. In order to do this I've added the following to my test:

```
protected $fixtures = [
    'app.Notifications',
    // ...
];

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->Notifications = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Notifications');
}

public function testGetNotifications()
{
    $userNotifications = $this->Notifications->find()->where(['user_id' => 1])->count();
    debug($userNotifications);
    die;
}
```

To explain my understanding of the code above:

- The `$fixtures` array contains `app.Notifications`. This is consistent to what's shown in the CakePHP docs regarding [Loading Fixtures in your Test Cases](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#loading-fixtures-in-your-test-cases). It specficially says:

> After you’ve created your fixtures, you’ll want to use them in your test cases. In each test case you should load the fixtures you will need. You should load a fixture for every model that will have a query run against it.

So my understanding is I'm loading the `NotificationsFixture.php` file referenced earlier.

- The `setUp()` method gives me a reference to the Model that interacts with the `notifications` table, i.e. `src/Model/Table/NotificationsTable.php`. Given that this is being run in a Test Suite - and after reviewing the docs - this should be interacting with the test database (`test_notification_db`) NOT the application database (`dev_notification_db`).
- The actual test uses the model in the point above and attempts to find notifications for a given user ID. The count in this case comes back as 400. In the application database there *are* 400 rows for the user ID given. However, in the fixture there are only 3 rows (all of which are for the user in question). Therefore this should come back as 3, not 400.

Upon debugging the full result set it's clear that the data is being loaded from `dev_notification_db` and not the test database, `test_notification_db`.

Why is this? If the purpose of the test suite is to be able to interact with the test database and the Fixtures are - quote - "records that will be inserted into the test database at the beginning of each test" then this is certainly not doing that.

What is missing here, or making it interact with the application's database and not the separate database for testing purposes?

Comment: `TblRegulatoryAlertsFixture` doesn't match the `NotificationsFixture.php` filename. That aside, by default CakePHP would look up connection names prefixed with `test_`, see **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#test-connections**. So it would look for `test_dev_notification_db` when a table uses the `dev_notification_db` connection. As mentioned in the next section, fixtures require the injector/extension to be set up and running, start with checking whether that is working properly, if the tests silently use the normal connection, then this could be the problem.

Comment: @ndm `TblRegulatoryAlertsFixture` shouldn't have been posted - that's my mistake! I was trying to rename things for the purpose of the post to make them more readable and have renamed it since this is cf. `NotificationsFixture`. In any case I think it's likely to be some naming problem as you've hinted towards.

Comment: To be more specific, the fixture injector/extension is where the test connection aliases are being configured, so if the injector/extension doesn't run, you'll naturally end up with the default connections being used. **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/TestSuite/Fixture/PHPUnitExtension.php#L36** / **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php#L137**

Comment: @ndm I added a `die` statement to the first line of `executeBeforeFirstTest()` which is one of the places you've linked to. When I re-ran my tests that `die` wasn't triggered, so I'm guessing it's not getting as far as this. When you say "if the injector/extension doesn't run" is there something particular that's needed to make that happen, or is it suppose to run automatically as part of the test process? I'm using `vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testGetNotifications` to run that individual test mentioned in my question.

Comment: You need to configure PHPUnit accordingly as shown here: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/testing.html#phpunit-configuration**. If you're using the "old" fixture system, you'd use the second variant, and in that case the extension wouldn't be used, but the fixture manager (the second code link in my comment above).

Comment: Having a second look at the docs, it seems something has been messed up, the example should use the fixture manager as shown here in the 3.x docs: **https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/testing.html#phpunit-configuration**. I'll get that fixed.